# How to upload a CSV file in FastAPI and convert it into a Pandas Dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, fastapi

I would like to upload a file to a FastAPI backend and convert it into a Pandas DataFrame. However, I don't seem to understand how to do that using FastAPI's [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) object. More specifically, what should I pass to the `pd.read_csv()` function?

Here is my FastAPI endpoint:

```py
@app.post("/upload")
async def upload_file(file: UploadFile):
    df = pd.read_csv("")
    print(df)
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

Comment: Please read [ask]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below are given various options on how to convert an uploaded file to FastAPI into a Pandas DataFrame. If you would also like to convert the DataFrame into JSON and return it to the client, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71205127/17865804). If you would like to use an `async def` endpoint instead of `def`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804) on how to read the file contents in an `async` way, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) to understand the difference between using `def` and `async def`. It would also be best to enclose the I/O operations (in the examples below) in a `try-except-finally` block (as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804)), so that you can catch/raise any possible exceptions and `close` the `file` properly, in order to release the object from memory and avoid potential errors.

Related answers on how to upload and read a CSV file can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74588435/17865804) (gives examples using Jinja2 Templates), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70655118/17865804) (converts the uploaded CSV file into JSON and returns it to the client) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76044533/17865804) (provides solutions without using external libraries).

### Option 1

Since [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) can accept a [`file-like`](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-like-object) object, you can pass the `file-like` object of [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) directly. [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#uploadfile) exposes an actual Python [`SpooledTemporaryFile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile) that you can  get using the `.file` attribute. Example is given below. Note: The [`pd.read_csv()` isn't an `async` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60368916), and hence, if you are about to use `async def` endpoint, it would be better to read the contents of the file using an `async` method, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804), and then pass the contents to `pd.read_csv()` using one of the reamining options below. Alternatively, you can use Starlette's [`run_in_threadpool()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/b8ea367b4304a98653ec8ce9c794ad0ba6dcaf4b/starlette/concurrency.py#L35) (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804)), which will run the `pd.read_csv(file.file)` in a separate thread to ensure that the main thread (where coroutines are run) does not get blocked.

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import pandas as pd

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    df = pd.read_csv(file.file)
    file.file.close()
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

### Option 2

Convert the bytes into a string and then load it into an in-memory text buffer (i.e., [`StringIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO)), which can be converted into a dataframe:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = file.file.read()
    s = str(contents,'utf-8')
    data = StringIO(s) 
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
    data.close()
    file.file.close()
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

### Option 3

Use an in-memory bytes buffer instead (i.e., [`BytesIO`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)), thus saving you the step of converting the bytes into a string as shown in Option 2:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
def upload_file(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    contents = file.file.read()
    data = BytesIO(contents)
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
    data.close()
    file.file.close()
    return {"filename": file.filename}
```

Comment: chris could you tell me one more thing how can i use this df variable in other functions too.

Comment: If you need read-only access to that variable, and you never expect it to be modified by some other process/request before reading it, as well as you don't plan on using [several workers](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/server-workers/) (each worker has its own variables and memory), you could either declare it as `global`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71383736/17865804), or store it on the `app` instance, as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71537393/17865804). See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65686318/17865804) for more options.