# input excel file from UI in fastapi

Tags: python, fastapi

Hi I'm trying the following for api input

```
def upload_excel_parser(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
 s_filename = file.filename
 unique_id = str(uuid4())
 project_id = s_filename + unique_id    
 df = pd.read_excel(file)   
 return "success"
```

also tried

```
df = pd.read_excel(file.file)
```

getting error
ValueError: Excel file format cannot be determined, you must specify an engine manually.

Is there some error in reading the file?

Comment: Shouldn't you `read()` the `file` first, to get the content of the file?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to upload a file in FastAPI and convert it into a Pandas Dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71477787/how-to-upload-a-file-in-fastapi-and-convert-it-into-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0):

pandas cannot directly read from a `UploadFile` - you need to do the following.

```
async def upload_excel_parser(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    content = await file.read()
    df = pd.read_excel(BytesIO(content))
    return "success"
```